# Can smd ferrite beads be avoided

Tags: pcb-design, emc, ferrite-bead

I am redesigning an input interface circuit for digital input. Its a basic signal conditioning circuit for reverse polarity protection, EMI ESD protection, and filtering voltage surges. For EMI EMC, ferrite beads are used in previous design. 
How can the use of smd ferrite-bead be avoided by using apt PCB designing techniques, still keeping the PCB immune to electromagnetic interference.

Comment: What is so wrong about using ferrite beads? When properly selected, they are a useful noise and emission suppression tool.

Comment: number of inputs is more, so its increasing system cost...n i need to optimize it.

Comment: Ever heard of "Penny wise, pound foolish?". Reducing component count comes with a change in performance, probably not even passing required EMC tests and subsequent costly redesigns.

Answer (score 3):

The best PWB design , I have seen for EMI was a high speed 16 channel Mux card from Nortel.  No ferrite was used to achieve CMMR of adjacent channel signal of 60 dB SNR and 20 dB margin on CISPRE , FCC, IEC EMI  with > 100MHz spectrum.

It was an 8 layer board with balanced differential controlled impedances with tracks on opposite layers with perfect matching, between ground planes and ground tracks between channels on the signal layers.

But then every CATV board and HDD board and commercial stepper application, I have seen uses ferrite to decouple in many areas where DC currents need low ESR , high CMRR,  low differential inductance but high lossy RF common mode impedance of a few hundred Ohms.

Low permeability ferrite is used for high power or RF, which  has more metal oxide than iron oxide. These are for >50MHz typ. and easy to tell because they are conductive.  Whereas high permeability ferrite is non conductive for ~<50MHz.

Keep in mind there are thousands of ferrite blends from Token, TDK, Murata and are cheap like Borscht in volume. Some are fussy about flux and cleaning fluids.

There are least 10 general EMC methods of control.  Must read the EMC Engineering book (my bible) by Henry W. Ott. Must be in 5th publication by now.  Over 800 pages.

Comment: Sometime counting components is not just saving a penny but losing a customer from EMC issues and lack of interference testing.

Answer (score 1):

For **inputs** it's relatively easy to avoid ferrite beads- all they do is introduce some hundreds of ohms of lossy impedance, and only at relatively high frequency.

Just replace them with a similar value resistor (or higher, if possible) and make sure the circuit still meets all the specifications.

Power (including grounds), and outputs are where they earn their keep.

Comment: My main aim is decreasing component count, so cant add resistor

Comment: Then I think you're not going to be able to achieve the same results. You can use resistor networks, which could reduce component count without undue compromise.